# How to let SQL have no crash if table doesn't have the column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many tables.e.g.: tableName1,tableName2...,tableNameN

Some table have the columnNames named 'ID','D1','D2' .

Some table only have the columnNames named 'ID','D1'.

if run the sql below:

```
SELECT D1,D2 FROM tableName1
SELECT D1,D2 FROM tableName2
SELECT D1,D2 FROM tableName3
...
SELECT D1,D2 FROM tableNameN
```

Because some table doesn't have 'D2' column ,it will crash in some table sql.

It will show 'invalid column name "D2"'

How to let SQL have no crash if table doesn't have the column name?

I hope if the table doesn't have 'D2',the column value of the sql result is default value which I assigned.

**Advanced Question:**

if table doesn't have multiple column which I want.

Some table have the columnNames named 'ID','D1','D2','D3'.

Some table only have the columnNames named 'ID','D1'.

I try this below, it's working.

```
select t.* 
from (select NULL as D2,NULL as D3) x cross apply
     (select D2,D3
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: @JohnWoo . . . It can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick to making this work:

```
select t.* 
from (select NULL as d2) x cross apply
     (select d1, d2
      from t
     ) t
```

If `d2` is in `t`, then it will resolve to `t.d2`.  Otherwise, it will resolve to `x.d2`.

This is about the only case where using qualified column names is not appropriate.